# Loading a html page in a div in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

below are 2 html pages ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Commision </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function loadpage(x)
{
    $('#centre').empty().load(x, function () {
    window.alert('Request complete');
});
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
#main {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:url(Images/header1.png);
  -moz-background-size: auto, cover; /* Firefox 3.6 */ 
    background-size: auto, cover; /* Chrome, Firefox 4.0+, Safari 4.1+, Opera 10+ and IE9 */
    width:100%;
    height:14%;
    overflow: hidden;

    z-index:250;
}
#centre {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:14%;
    width:100%;
    height:82%;
    z-index:240;
}
#smoothmenu1 {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:40%;
    bottom:0px;
    height:26px;
        overflow: hidden;

    z-index:220;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:4%;
        overflow: hidden;

    z-index:2;
}

.com {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px; 
}
#cntr {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:-1px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:50;
}
#insideCentre {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:10%;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    z-index:12;
}
#initProfile {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:70%;
-moz-border-radius:12px;
-webkit-border-radius:12px;
border-radius:14px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:14;
}
.aFont
{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

#aboutMSL {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
-moz-border-radius:12px;
-webkit-border-radius:12px;
border-radius:12px; 
background:url(Images/gclip.png);
    overflow: hidden;


    z-index:18;
}
#aboutBody {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:14%;
    width:100%;
    height:86%;
border-right-color:#666;
    border-left-style:dotted;
        overflow: hidden;

    border-left-width:thin; z-index:23;
}
#tech {
    position:absolute;
top :50%;
right:0px;
-moz-border-radius:12px;
-webkit-border-radius:12px;
border-radius:12px; width:30%;
    height:30%;
    z-index:19;
}
#tech_header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
-moz-border-radius:12px;
-webkit-border-radius:12px;
border-radius:12px;
    background:url(Images/gclip.png);
    overflow: hidden;

    z-index:20;
}
#tech_body {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
bottom:10%;
width:100%;
    height:50%;
    z-index:21;
        overflow: hidden;

}
.sFont {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
#sShow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:30%;
    height:40%;
    z-index:51;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
<div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"  onclick="loadpage('a.html')">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="loadpage('c.html')">S</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="loadpage('v.html')">C</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Commx</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="loadpage('b.html')">V</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: left" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="centre">

</div>

<div id="footer" align="center" class="com" >Commision</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>


<style type="text/css">
#top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;

            background:url(Images/gclip.png);

    z-index:3;
}
#c1  {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:25px;
    z-index:5;
            border-bottom: 0.5px solid #778;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="PCentre">
<div id="c1">Column 1</div>
<div id="Pbody"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to load the 2nd html page into centre div of 1st html page using query , the application works fine in firefox but not in chrome , in chrome the div elements in page 2 are not getting placed as they were when i ran this application in firefox (i tried to run the application from localhost/127.0.0.1)

Comment: maybe you need to use `<iframe>` because your second page have a full html code with `<head>` and `<body>` tags

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to load the particular wrapper div inside:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"  onclick="loadpage('a.html #PCentre')">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onClick="loadpage('c.html #PCentre')">S</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="loadpage('v.html #PCentre')">C</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Commx</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="loadpage('b.html #PCentre')">V</a></li>
</ul>   //-----------------------------------^^^^^^^^----------this one
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

**Loading Page Fragments**

The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the `url` parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

We could modify the example above to use only part of the document that is fetched:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

You'll want to give the `<body>` of the second page an ID, and reference this ID in your call to `load` in order to insert the *contents of the body* into your `<div>`, rather than inserting an entire HTML page into the `<div>` which results in invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @shnisaka is correct - the fact that you are trying to load a complete page, doctype and all, into another page inherently suggests that you are trying to load a stand-alone page into another stand-alone page. The only way to do this, while maintaining the independence of each page is to use an iFrame. If this is not your intention, you may want to re-think your IA.

If your goal is to simply extract some particular section(s) of the document, e.g. the body and stylesheets, then the best practice would be to extract those nodes/elements and insert them. However, this will also open your page up to potentially conflicting stylesheets and/or scripts.

This issue can be resolved as-is via a code solution, but I highly recommend that you take a look at what you are doing, think about what your goal is, and consider the potential issues from a compatibility, extensibility, and maintainability standpoint.